# setTimeout not working on server

Tags: jquery, server, settimeout

I use Ajax to get data from database, And i use setTimeout for delay data to show.
But in my computer, I use Wamp.It work to delay data to show.
But,When i upload file to server. Data is not delay to show. What Happen?

This is sample code.

```
$.getJSON('xxx.php',{'xxx' : xxx},function(data)
    {           
        $.each(data,function(key, val) 
        {
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                $.getJSON('xxx.php',{'xxx' : xxx},function(data)
                {
                    //show data.
                });
            },key*450);
        });
    });
```

Comment: check Json 'val' in console .

Answer (score 0):

That looks fine to me. Worth checking whether the `data` is an array, in which case, `key` would be 0 with the first element, which means, with `key*450`, a timeout of 0ms.

jQuery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/) about `$.each`'s second callback argument:

> Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )